# What kind of object are the solutions of the Knizhnik-Zamolodchikov Equations

Tags: quantum-groups

I am reading about the KZ equations in Kassel's Quantum groups. In definition XIX.3.1 (page 455) he defines the differential system $(KZ_n)$ as 
$$
dw = \frac{h}{2\pi\sqrt{-1}} \sum_{1 \leq i <j \leq n} \frac{t_{ij}}{z_i-z_j}(dz_i- dz_j)w $$

where the  $t_{ij}$ are some element of the universal enveloping algebra $U(\mathfrak{g})$ for some Lie algebras $\mathfrak{g}$. In this definition "$w = w(z_1, \dots, z_n)$ is a function on $Y_n$ with values in $W^{\otimes n}$" where $Y_n = \{(z_1, \dots, z_n) \vert  i \neq j \Rightarrow z_i \neq z_j\}$ and $V$ is a *finite* dimensional $\mathfrak{g}$-module.

At this point the solutions are then simply foncitons on some complex parameters taking value in the $V^{\otimes n}$. However, when doing the proof of the Drinfled-Kohno theorem , Kassel makes some change of coordinates for the case $n=3$ and we have the following equation (equation 7.3, page 469 in Kassel's book):

$$ w(z_1,z_2,z_3) = (z_3 - z_1)^{\hbar(t_{12} + t_{23} + t_{13})}G(z)$$
where $z = \frac{z_2-z_1}{z_3-z_1}$ and $G(z)$ is a formal serie in $t_{12}$ and $t_{23}$ with coefficients being analytic functions in $z$. This seems to indicate that the solutions are actually taking value in in $U(\mathfrak{g})^{\otimes 3} [[h]]$ and this is where my confusion comes from. Especially since it does not seem to be coming from the case where $V = U(\mathfrak{g})$ for this is not finite dimensional.

Maybe the explanation for this is in the paragraph at the end of page 457 but I don't really understand what he is doing here neither.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are really 3 levels at which you can define this equation:

1. for functions
   $$G:Y_n \longrightarrow V^{\otimes n}$$ where $V$ is a f.d. module and $h$ is a complex number. You can then take a formal expansion around $h=0$ and regard $G$ as being valued in $V^{\otimes n}[[h]]$.
2. for functions
   $$G:Y_n \longrightarrow U(\mathfrak g)^{\otimes n}[[h]].$$
   This only makes sense formally (by which I mean that you need formal power series in $h$).
3. for $n=3$ and up to some change of variable as you say, you get a version where $G$ takes values in the algebra of formal power series in two non commuting variables $A,B$. This is the one appearing in section 6 of Kassel's book. More generally, for arbitrary $n$ you have a version of the KZ equation taking values in the algebra of so-called horizontal chords diagrams.

The general theory of this kind of equation really has been done only in case 1, so in the other 2 cases, in the literature, existence and uniqueness of solutions are proved in a somewhat ad hoc way but this isn't hard.

The relation between 3 and 2 just boils down to the substitution $A\mapsto h t_{1,2}, B\mapsto h t_{2,3}$. So in equation 7.3 that you mention in your message, $G$ does indeed takes value in $U(\mathfrak g)^{\otimes 3}[[h]]$ (so it's a formal power series in $h$, not in $t_{1,2}$ and $t_{2,3}$).

The relation between 2 and 1 at the level of equations is that the former specializes to the latter through the algebra map
$$U(\mathfrak g)^{\otimes n}[[h]] \rightarrow End(V^{\otimes n}[[h]])$$
coming from the action of $\mathfrak g$ on $V$.
In terms of solutions, if $z_0 \in Y_n$ then there is a unique solution $G$ of $2$ defined in a neighborhood of $z_0$ such that $G(z_0)=1$, the unit of $U(\mathfrak g)$. Now if $v \in V^{\otimes n}$, then the function $$\tilde G:z\longmapsto G(z)\cdot v$$

is by construction the unique solution of equation 1 satisfying $\tilde G(z_0)=v$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it certainly helps a lot. I am just wondering what you mean exactly by "You can then take a formal expansion around h=0 ".  This seems to be closely related to the paragraph at the of page 457 in section 3 of Kassel's book.

If I understand correctly, you say that what Kassel is doing in his book is that you can understand equation 7.3 with $G$ taking values in $U(\mathfrak{g})^{\otimes n}[[h]]$ from which one can build a solution of this same equation this time taking value in $V^{\otimes n} [[h]]$, which leads to a solution of $(KZ)$.

Comment: That's right, you get a function taking values in $U(g)^{\otimes n}[[h]]$, which can further be specialized to a solution in $V^{\otimes n}[[h]]$ for any choice of $v \in V$. Now it just so happen that if $V$ is finite dimensional this is actually analytic in $h$, ie it converges to an actual (as opposed to formal) solution in $V^{\otimes n}$, but this doesn't really play a role in this story (it does play a role if you want the stronger version of the KD theorem where $h$ is specialized to a generic complex number).

Comment: In fact you don't need all the $V$'s to be the same. At the end of the day, the bottom line is you get the KZ associator as an element in $U(g)^{\otimes 3}[[h]]$ the action of which describes the holonomy from 0 to 1 of solutions valued in $(V \otimes W \otimes Z)[[h]]$ for any f.d. modules $V,W,Z$, and this is natural w.r.t $g$-morphisms.

Comment: Can we then  understand $w(z_1,z_2,z_3) = (z_3 - z_1)^{\hbar(t_{12} + t_{23} + t_{13})}\tilde{G}(z)$ to be a solution of $(KZ_3)$? I ask this because we want to link this to the monodromy of the $KZ$ system.

Comment: Well, yes, it is a solution of the (formal) KZ equation valued in whatever $G$ is valued in. Nothe monodromy can also be described at either of those level, that was the point of my previous comment somehow.

Comment: Just to be clear: all of those are rightfully called "a solution of the KZ equation". What does depends on the context is what "the KZ equation" means, sorry if this led to some confusion. People don't always clearly distinguishes between 2 and 3, since there isn't much lost in working formally and imply that whatever result you care about also holds for the specialized version whenever it makes sense.

Comment: I think my confusion comes more from a question which is implicit in my post. At some point we want to show that the representation of $B_n$ given by the monodromy of $dw = \frac{h}{2\pi\sqrt{-1}} \sum_{1 \leq i <j \leq n} \frac{t_{ij}}{z_i-z_j}(dz_i- dz_j)w$ is equal to the one coming from the top. quasi. bialgebra $U(\mathfrak{g})[[h]]$ with associator $\phi_{KZ}$ and R-matrix $e^{ht/2}$. This is why I feel like I need some kind of concrete solution of $dw = \frac{h}{2\pi\sqrt{-1}} \sum_{1 \leq i <j \leq n} \frac{t_{ij}}{z_i-z_j}(dz_i- dz_j)w$ to check that those two are somewhat related.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "concrete" here, but you do have particular solutions whose monodromy can be expressed using $\Phi$, that's of course the whole point, namely those taking the value 1 in some appropriate "asymptotic zone" in Drinfeld's language. Btw this discussion might be starting go be too long for comments, feel free to send me an email (the address of my webpage is in my profile).